# Can we get rid of [mysql-management]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

As far as I know, there is no tool or technology called MySQL-management. The [mysql-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-management) tag has no usage guidance or tag wiki. It's unclear to me what the purpose of the tag is and it seems that all the people that used it also didn't know. Most questions have something to do with MySQL, but some are unrelated to MySQL.

I propose to go over the questions and retag the ones that have nothing to do with MySQL and then merge the rest into [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql). Are there any objections or alternative proposals?

Comment: The tag seems to be (heavily) abused. There are a lot where they are tagged with [[tag:mysql-management]] and then something else entirely, such as [[tag:sql-server]]. More than happy to clean up some of those.

Comment: This is the current [oldest non-deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35420/2821954) and it looks like a meta tag separating questions with managing MySQL database (DBA-related?) from writing MySQL query. Also, related tag: [tag:database-management].

Comment: I've removed the tag from questions I am confident that they aren't to do with MySQL from the search page. Most of these were created in more recent years and many seemed to be used instead of [[tag:ssms]] (which also would often be the incorrect tag and [[tag:sql-server]] should be used, or was also).

Comment: I have no idea what to retag [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4832463/2029983) with; by current standards it's *way* off topic. Retagging it with MySQL is wrong, as it's not about MySQL at all.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a tool. The tag handles the administration of a MySQL server. It isn't abused; it is only referring to administration, so synonymize it.

Comment: @nbk administration is rarely on topic on [so] ; if the questions *are* about the administration of MySQL Servers then they are probably on the wrong site.  Though certainly it was being misused/abused in more recent years, after the number of questions I editted that had nothing to do with MySQL .

Comment: @Larnu DBA is the one possible sitey but
 The people ask here, because they get here the same answers and they are on topic

Comment: That people ask on [so] doesn't make it on topic, @nbk . People ask for tool recommendations all the time; it is *still* off-topic.

Comment: I've had a couple more looks through the questions, and I *think* that isn't related to [[tag:mysql]] I've retagged appropriately . There were a couple of outliers I found yesterday that were tagged with [[tag:mysql]], but were about a different RDBMS. There may well be some I've missed so a second set of eyes would be good, but it's in a better position to be merged into [[tag:mysql]] in my opinion.

Comment: Encountered this tag again today on a [[tag:sql-server]] question. @Dharman I can go through the tag again and see if there's anything "new", though with the strike is a merge likely to occur? Should I set a calendar reminder for 6-8 weeks? :)

Comment: @ThomA If you can go over it, I would appreciate it. Please ping me here and then I will merge it.

Comment: Thanks @Dharman . I've cleaned up a few outliers, everything else mentions MySQL explicitly, such as in the tags, title or post content (with the exception of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6538208/2029983). Looks good to be merged now.